# How can I create combinations of elements in a list one by one?

Tags: python, combinations

I have a list of elements [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], I want to generate combinations one by one, like [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5], etc.

I tried using itertools.combinations but that makes a list of all possible combinations, which takes up too much memory space.

How do I access each new combination right when it is generated?

Comment: Iterate through `list(itertools.combinations(a,3))` where `a = [1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: Do you want to use `generator`?

Comment: But itertools.combinations is a generator, thus there shouldn't be a memory problem?

Comment: myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. list(itertools.combinations(myList, 3)) gives me a list of combinations, [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], ... , [3, 4, 5]. This works fine for small myLists, but for a list with thousands of combinations it takes up a lot of memory space and time. I want to check if each combination of numbers can make a valid triangle. So I want to generate one combination, check it, and stop if it fits, instead of making a list of all the combinations and then checking them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I access each new combination right when it is generated?

Use a `for` loop, like so:

```
import itertools
for a, b, c in itertools.combinations(range(1, 101), 3):
    if a**2 + b**2 == c**2:
        print(a, b, c)
```

> `itertools.combinations` makes a list of all possible combinations

No, it doesn't.

`itertools.combinations()` is a [*generator function*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators). When used in a `for` loop, only one result is returned at a time. No `list` of all the results is ever created.

Comment: N.b. You don't say if you are using Python2 or Python3. `range()` in Python3 returns a generator object. `range()` in Python2 returns a `list`. If you are conserving memory, use `xrange()` in Python2.